# What is the reason behind doctors giving some medicines after/before the meal?

Tags: medications, practice-of-medicine, time-of-day, meal

How they give medicine like you have to take in early morning without taking any food?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). The general answer would be that food might interfere with the medicine, but there are many different interactions - if you [edit] your question to make it more specific (name a medicine or a group of medicines) we could write a more detailed answer explaining specific interactions in that particular case. For more information on asking policies on health SE please check out [ask] and the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple answer**: Because that is just the medication guidelines. Some medications, because of onset of actions, effect of stomach acid, upsetting stomach and other factors need to be taken on or off a full stomach. The doctors know this, because there is evidence based practice proving what works the best. To make sure the meds work best for you it is best to consult your prescriber on how best to take a pill, there are many routes.

[NHS.UK](http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/866.aspx?CategoryID=73) showed some common reasons:

To take meds with food:

- NSAIDS and Corticosteroids can cause stomach irritation
- Some HIV medicines (ritonavir, saquinavir and nelfinavir)
- Oral diabetic meds are usually taken with foods to lower blood sugar afterwards.

Meds taken after meals:

- Nystatin when used orally can be washed away with food.
- Antiacids can be taken immediately after or before a meal for heartburn.

Meds taken before meals:

- Vitamin C absorbs better in a acidic environment so before meals is better.

[Graph](http://m.globalrph.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.globalrph.com%2Fdrugfoodrxn.htm&utm_referrer=#2865) that shows med times